# Fix: Lazy loading in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, lazy-loading

Python is selecting just 18 elements out of possible 100 due to lazy loading of elements, on page load, just 18 will be loaded and on scrolling the new elements will be uploaded deleting the previously loaded elements, how can I fix this so that it stores all 100 elements in the `persons` list and clicks each of those elements.

[DOM element structure of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt296.png)

```
d = 0
itr = 1
time.sleep(17)

while True:
    persons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view']")
    print(len(persons))
    for i, person in zip(names, persons):
        time.sleep(4) 
        persons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view']")
        if d >= len(persons):
            break
        i = names[d]
        person = persons[d]
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", person)
        time.sleep(3) 
        person.click()
```

Comment: ```names``` is just a list I am pulling from the names variable I have stored above the code block the major issues is the persons lazy loading.

Comment: Coupe of things are  not clear in your code. Like what is the use of variable d ? As it is always 0. So is it you always want to click first element from list ? Assuming your requirement is to click all the element identified by browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view']"). Please see the Answer section.

Comment: @rahulrai the purpose of ```d``` is actually to click the current value of d in the iteration. d could be between 1 to 100. To select the right button to click. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See answer I have provided. I am clicking all links , you can take idea n perform your task .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Click all the elements on a page where new elements are getting loaded after scrolling down and old elements are getting disappeared.

```
while True:
    # Get screen height upon page loading for the first time 
    last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    #Get the list of elements 
    persons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view']")

    # Lopp through all elements and click on them
    for i in range (1,len(persons)+1):
        # As after every click page will be reloaded, getting fresh reference to element every time , so that wont get stale element exception
        linkXpath = "(//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view'])["+str(i)+"]"
        WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, linkXpath ))).click()
    # Scroll down to bottom
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)

    #Get new height of screen
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: Above should work. I could not test in my local as you have nor shared the page link. Let me know if any issue.

Comment: Please upvote if it helps you solving your problem. It will help others n myself in turn. Cheers :)