# missing values while scraping Oddsportal using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This scraper scrapes a dataframe from https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/ like the below dataframe:

scraper:

```
import os
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd
from math import nan
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


    class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'p.whitespace-nowrap',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])',
        'score': 'a:has(a[title])+div.hidden',
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)',
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    pgDate = pgSoup.select_one('h1.title[id="next-matches-h1"]')
    if pgDate: pgDate = pgDate.get_text().split(',', 1)[-1].strip()
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
                evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in
                [':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type']]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))
            if pgDate: current_group['date'] = pgDate

        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}

        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        evtTeams = evt.select('a div>a[title]')
        evtRow['game'] = ' – '.join(a['title'] for a in evtTeams)
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)
    return events


def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[set]>div:last-child a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)")))
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    scroll_pause_time = 2

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    game_data = GameData()
    game_keys = [a for a, av in game_data.__dict__.items() if isinstance(av, list)]
    for row in generate_matches(soup, defaultVal=nan):
        for k in game_keys: getattr(game_data, k).append(row.get(k, nan))
    if return_urls:
        if return_urls:
            a_cont = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tabs'})
            if a_cont is None:
                a_tags = []
            else:
                a_tags = a_cont.find_all('a', {'class': 'h-8', 'href': True})
            urls = [
                'https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags
                if not a_tag['href'].startswith('#')  # sections in current page
                and 'active-item-calendar' not in a_tag['class']  # current page
            ]
            print(pd.DataFrame(urls, columns=['urls']))  # If you want to see the URLs then uncomment this line else, comment it out.
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    games = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    url_today = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer'
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=(url_today, True))
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)
    # ############################ BUILD  DATAFRAME 

    game_data_dfList, added_todayGame = [], False
    for game_data in game_data_results:
        try:
            game_data_dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__))
            if not added_todayGame:
                game_data_dfList += [pd.DataFrame(game_data_today.__dict__)]
                added_todayGame = True
        except Exception as e:
            game_n = len(game_data_dfList) + 1
            print(f'Error tabulating game_data_df#{game_n}:\n{repr(e)}')
        # finally: pass ## [ redundant ]
    try:
        games = pd.concat(game_data_dfList, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error concatenating DataFrames:', repr(e))
    # #########################################################################
    print('!?NO GAMES?!' if games is None else games)
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal  # a little extra insurance
    import gc

    gc.collect()

games.to_csv()


df:

|    | date        | time   | game                        | score   |   home_odds |   draw_odds |   away_odds | country                | league              |
|---:|:------------|:-------|:----------------------------|:--------|------------:|------------:|------------:|:-----------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 | 13 Mar 2023 | 00:00  | Mrkonjic Grad – Kozara      | 2:2     |        1.94 |        3.42 |        3.42 | Bosnia and Herzegovina | Prva Liga - RS      |
|  1 | 13 Mar 2023 | 00:00  | Patrocinense – Democrata SL | 2:0     |        2.01 |        3.12 |        3.74 | Brazil                 | Campeonato Mineiro  |
|  2 | 13 Mar 2023 | 00:00  | Cameta – Bragantino         | 2:0     |        2.2  |        3.15 |        3.05 | Brazil                 | Campeonato Paraense |
|  3 | 13 Mar 2023 | 00:00  | Tonnerre – Aigle Moungo     | 1:1     |        3.3  |        3.2  |        2.16 | Cameroon               | Elite Two           |
|  4 | 13 Mar 2023 | 00:00  | Vendsyssel – Sonderjyske    | 2:3     |        2.73 |        3.44 |        2.4  | Denmark                | 1st Division        |
```

However, instead of getting just 7 URLs from [image: desired urls]
from

```
if return_urls:
if return_urls:
a_cont = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tabs'})
if a_cont is None:
a_tags = []
else:
a_tags = a_cont.find_all('a', {'class': 'h-8', 'href': True})
urls = [
                'https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags
if not a_tag['href'].startswith('#')  # sections in current page
and 'active-item-calendar' not in a_tag['class']  # current page
            ]
```

I am however getting the calendar list of urls i.e. 41 urls in this case which is not desired.

Also, the dataframe scraped is missing score values.

[image: scores]

While the current output is:

|  | date | time | game | score | home_odds | draw_odds | away_odds | country | league |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 27 Feb 2023 | 00:00 | St Eloi Lupopo (Drc) – Al Akhdar (Lby) | nan | 1.61 | 3.5 | 5.62 | Africa | CAF Confederation Cup |
| 1 | 27 Feb 2023 | 00:00 | Mazembe (Drc) – Monastir (Tun) | nan | 1.54 | 3.5 | 7.36 | Africa | CAF Confederation Cup |
| 2 | 27 Feb 2023 | 00:00 | Sao Francisco – Tapajos | nan | 3.55 | 3.33 | 1.99 | Brazil | Campeonato Paraense |
| 3 | 27 Feb 2023 | 00:00 | Inter Star – Dynamik | nan | 1.83 | 3.24 | 4.33 | Burundi | Primus League |
| 4 | 27 Feb 2023 | 00:00 | Vital'O – Kayanza | nan | 1.49 | 4.04 | 5.97 | Burundi | Primus League |

How can I get the correct URLs and the columns correctly populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `urls`, try using CSS selector as below:

```py
            # a_cont # <-- no longer necessary
            ac_sel = 'div:has(>a.active-item-calendar)' # a_cont selector
            a_sel = f'{ac_sel}>a[href]:not([href^="#"]):not(.active-item-calendar)'
            a_tags = soup.select(a_sel)
            urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com'+a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
```

---

And for the score, just change `evtSel['score']` selector to **`'a a[title]+div:has(+a[title])'`**; but note that the `score` field will now contain `–` instead of `None`/`nan` for future games...

Comment: Thanks for this. Also, is there any way you can 'teach me' the scraping? I am unable to get it. Any other platform would do. I am ready to share my credentials if thats alright with you for that.

Comment: @PyNoob It's mostly just getting familiar [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) (and [soupsieve](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/) which [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) uses to search) and a lot of practice with the inspect tab. I'm not really very good at explaining things outside of an example, but I could take you step by step for the selectors used in this solution [and/or for scraping another site, if you prefer]. Do you use discord?